Is a Rational Map Possible Between Elliptic Curves of Orders 19 and 18?
I'm exploring the relationship between elliptic curves and their orders. I have two elliptic curves:
E1: An elliptic curve with order 19.
E2: An elliptic curve with order 18.
Since the order of E1 is prime, I know that it cannot be isogenous to E2. Furthermore, they don't have the same order.
My question is: Is it possible to construct a rational map between E1 and E2?
If a rational map exists, could you please provide some guidance on how to approach finding it? Or, if such a map is not possible, can you explain why?

Firstly, your claims are true only over finite fields. If I choose an isogeny with kernel $\mu_{19} \times \mathbb Z/18$ there may be a counterexample over some number field. Second, a rational map of smooth proj curves is a morphim, so no.
